# what is worth vimxfer

Tags: vim, vimrc

So I readed someones vimrc file (or at least I think it is) with maps like this:

```
nmap <leader>r :r $HOME/.vimxfer<cr>
nmap <leader>w :'a<leader>.w! $HOME/.vimxfer<cr>
```

what is this vimxfer file? for what is worth? I haven't found any info about it

Answer (score 2):

`.vimxfer` is just the name of a file in that person's home directory. It looks like they're using it as some sort of staging area for transferring text from one place to another.